# Is there a setting to enable the context menu for the integrated console in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using Visual Studio Code on my Mac I'm able to right click in the integrated console and get a context menu. Below is a picture of the context menu that I get when I right click.

[image: Visual Studio Code context menu for integrated console]

Now when I try to do the same thing on Windows it just pastes whatever is in my clipboard. Is there a setting I can enable that will give me the context menu on Windows as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "default",
```

Comment: Note: for anyone who runs across this in the future the setting has changed to `"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "default"`